# How to order the records using mysql query?

Tags: mysql, database

I have User table that contains the following columns id,ancestor_id,parent_id,level. I want to list the users based on the parent_id ordered by level.

```
select id, name, ancestor_id, parent_id, level from users;
+------+---------+-------------+-----------+-------+
| id   | name    | ancestor_id | parent_id | level |
+------+---------+-------------+-----------+-------+
|    1 | John    |        NULL |         1 |     0 |
|    2 | Mark    |           1 |         1 |     0 |
|    3 | Stephen |           1 |         1 |     1 |
|    4 | Richard |           1 |         2 |     0 |
|    5 | Michael |           1 |         2 |     1 |
|    6 | Paul    |           1 |         2 |     2 |
|    7 | Emily   |           1 |         6 |     0 |
|    8 | Mathew  |           1 |         6 |     1 |
+------+---------+-------------+-----------+-------+
```

Output:

```
John
  Mark (first level)
    Richard (2nd level)
    Michael (2nd level)
    Paul    (2nd level)
      Emily (3rd level)
      Mathew (3rd level)
  Stephen(first level)
```

How to write the mysql to list the users ordered by level of their appropriate parents?

Comment: By creating multiple joins with a different alias, then ordering by those alias' and level

Comment: Is the amount of levels finite or infinite?

Comment: @ShimonRachlenko level is finite. maximum level is 5

Comment: `order by parent_id ASC, level ASC`